# django-cms apphook + cms flat pages in menu

Tags: python, django, django-cms

In current setup i have a page with apphook + cms attached menu.
How can I add CMS flat subpages for this page?

Adding pages gives 404 as it fails on apphook urls.py.

Comment: Have you restarted your server since adding the app hook?

Comment: I managed to fix this, it was due a pattern matching and return 404 because of the view logic. Solution was to change that url pattern and create a simple TemplateView :)